# How to make javascript variable dynamic for timer

Tags: javascript, timer

okay I have a timer script that counts down and is fed a date in this format:

```
var year="2015";    

var month="11";      

var day="18";
```

I am trying figure out how to dynamically populate the above variables so that the timer resets every wed at 8pm. So on wed 18, 2015 those variables would dynamically change to:

```
var year="2015";

var month="11";      

var day="25";
```

and keep going or would it just be better to have a user input the date in a form to populate those variables with the correct info. I would rather it all be automatic though, if possible of course.

Script that uses the variables:

```js
/*
Count down until any date script-
By JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
Over 200+ free scripts here!
Modified by Robert M. Kuhnhenn, D.O. 
on 5/30/2006 to count down to a specific date AND time,
on 10/20/2007 to a new format, and 1/10/2010 to include
time zone offset.
*/

var current="Citadel has reset!";    //-->enter what you want the script to display when the target date and time are reached, limit to 20 characters

var year="2015";    //-->Enter the count down target date YEAR

var month="11";      //-->Enter the count down target date MONTH

var day="18";       //-->Enter the count down target date DAY

var hour="22";      //-->Enter the count down target date HOUR (24 hour clock)

var minute="00";    //-->Enter the count down target date MINUTE

var tz=-5;        //-->Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC (see http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/index.htm to find the timezone offset for your location)

//    DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW!
var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

function countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min){

 theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d;thehour=hr;theminute=min;

 var today=new Date();

 var todayy=today.getYear();

 if (todayy < 1000) {todayy+=1900;}

 var todaym=today.getMonth();

 var todayd=today.getDate();

 var todayh=today.getHours();

 var todaymin=today.getMinutes();

 var todaysec=today.getSeconds();

 var todaystring1=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;

 var todaystring=Date.parse(todaystring1)+(tz*1000*60*60);

 var futurestring1=(montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hr+":"+min);

 var futurestring=Date.parse(futurestring1)-(today.getTimezoneOffset()*(1000*60));

 var dd=futurestring-todaystring;

 var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);

 var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);

 var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);

 var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

 if(dday<=0&&dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=0){

  document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML=current;

  document.getElementById('count2').style.display="inline";

  document.getElementById('count2').style.width="390px";

  document.getElementById('dday').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('dhour').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('dmin').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('dsec').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('days').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('hours').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('minutes').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('seconds').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('spacer1').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('spacer2').style.display="none";

  return;

 }else {

  document.getElementById('count2').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML=dday;

  document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML=dhour;

  document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML=dmin;

  document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML=dsec;

  setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)",1000);

 }

}
```

Comment: Show the timer script you are currently sending the year, month and day arguments to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `Date` object for this.

When your timer is triggered you could do the following:

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day);

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

year = date.getFullYear().toString();
month = date.getMonth().toString();
day = date.getDate().toString(); //Note: not date.getDay() even though that seems more correct.
```

You could also just use a `Date` object in the first place instead of the three separate string variables to avoid creating/parsing/converting between different types.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will do that!